# censoring words within html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function DOMcensor(word) {
  let regexwordfilter = `[ ^]?${word}[ $]?`
  regexwordfilter = new RegExp(regexwordfilter,"gmi");
  console.log(regexwordfilter);
  let bodystring = document.body.innerHTML;
  bodystring = bodystring.replace(regexwordfilter,` ${"*".repeat(word.length)} `);
  document.body.innerHTML = bodystring;
}
DOMcensor("img")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src=https://www.jaipuriaschoolsbanaras.in/babatpur/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/blank-img.jpg>
<h1>img</h1>
```

I'm trying to make a function that gets a word and censors it in an html document but the function I made causes some problems if the word is contained within tags see code example it should block the img inside the h1 tag but not the img in the name if the img tag how can I specify that I want to only block text and not tags or tag's attributes?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with only regexp. You'll need parser for this. You can implement a simpler version where you check that the string is not a tag name, but for ignoring attributes you'll need a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a function like this:

```
function censorWord(el, word) { 
  if (el.children.length > 0) { 
    Array.from(el.children).forEach(function(child){ 
      censorWord(child, word) 
    }) 
  } else { 
    if (el.innerText) { 
      el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, "g"), "***") 
    } 
  }  
}
```

and

`censorWord(document.body, "someWord")`

Comment: if i use this function with word phone for example it will show the word telephone as tele*** which isnt the intention i only mean to block the word if it shows up by its self